# ASP.NET MVC Riddle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Explain how this could print out two different values:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IList<Models.AModel>>" %>

<%
int i = -1;
foreach (var m in AModel){
    i++;
%>
<td><%= Html.TextBox(string.Format("[{0}].TheName", i), m.TheName) %> <%= m.TheName %></td>
<% } %>
```

For example, if theList contains three elements {TheName: "A"} and {TheName: "B"} and {TheName: "C"}, it will print:

```
<td><input name="[0].TheName" type="text" value="A">B</td>
<td><input name="[1].TheName" type="text" value="B">C</td>
<td><input name="[2].TheName" type="text" value="C">A</td>
```

Totally baffled.

I'll give votes for guesses and answer to the best guess, even if it's not the answer. To start out:

-TheName does not have any special code in the getter.

EDIT: Clarified the question with better examples (as I've discovered them), polished up the code to match suggestions. Still have the problem. As you can see, it appears the two lists are somehow out of order.

Comment: I don't understand the question, if the `firstElement.TheName = 'A'` and `secondElement.TheName = 'B'` whats wrong with printing `A B`?

Comment: MVC doesn't print, so what does the output really look like (HTML tags and all)?  Where's the opening <td> tag?  What are you trying to achieve with the Html.TextBox code?  Why is there a colon in front of Html.TextBox instead of an = sign?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: Excellent question, edited to clarify.

Comment: @Hightechrider This was a bit ambiguous, I've fixed it.

Comment: @stefan-mai Is that all the code that is relevant to the question? Where is `AModel` declared? does `AModel.TheName` have a weird getter that returns random results?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: No, I included that in the question. It's a simple TheName { get; set; }. I'd love to post a minimal example but I actually am not sure where the complexity lies myself, so I don't know what "minimal" actually is :(.

Comment: @Stefan, your code must differ from what you posted.  You haven't declared `AModel` which you're looping with (should that read `foreach (var m in Model)`)?  Unless your `IList<Models.AModel>` implementation you're using for the model is a very strange custom collection or there's some background threadery going on, I don't see how your output is possible.  Perhaps if you showed your controller and model code, we'll be able to spot the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a partial dump of the code?  There are a number of oddities:

1. You're using `<%:` with `Html.TextBox`, which doesn't make sense.  `<%:` HTML-encodes output, so it doesn't make sense that you'd be using it to print a `TextBox`.
2. You've got a closing `</td>` tag in your loop, but no opening `<td>` tag.

**Update**:

After your edit, it just looks to me like your list/enumerable must be doing something bizarre (or your posted output isn't the actual output)  You should show us how you're populating your model.

Comment: Excellent points, though it unfortunately doesn't effect the output. I've made the changes to the question though, thanks!

Comment: I'm not expecting it to be in order, I'm expecting elements on the same line to be aligned. This looks like the output to some sort of circular buffer...

Comment: This is not the correct answer, but was the most helpful. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not correct at all. *Jacob* has mentioned some of em.

Even if you are sure this code works then i think it has something to do with List item being bound to view and something happens that shows next value...

Comment: Care to elaborate on "something happens"?